# Search slice of pandas columns for value occurrence, get indices/mask of occurrences, then use that to index into a second slice of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-slicing

I have a large dataframe (500K rows x 100 cols) and **want to do the following search-and-masking operation efficiently, but I can't find the right pandas/numpy incantation; better still if it can be vectorized**:

- on each row, the N columns `m1,m2,...,m6` can contain distinct values from 1..9, or else trailing NaNs. (The NaNs are there for a very good reason, to prevent aggregation/taking sum/mean/etc. on nonexistent records when we process the output from this step; it is very strongly desirable that you preserve the NaNs)

  - distinctness: it is guaranteed that the columns `m<i>` will contain at most one occurrence of each of the values 1..9
- columns `x1,x2,...,x6` are associated with the columns `m<i>`, and  contain some integer values
- **For each possible value `v` in range 1..9** (I will manually sweep v from 1:9 at top-level of my analysis, don't worry about that part), **I want to do the following**:

  - on each row where that value `v` occurs in one of the `m<i>`, find which column `m<i>` equals `v` (either as boolean mask/array/indices/anything else you prefer)
  - on rows where `v` doesn't occur in `m<i>`, preferably I don't want any result for that row, not even NaN
  - then I want to use that intermediate boolean mask/array/indices/whatever to slice the corresponding value from the `x<i>` (`x1,x2,...,x6`) on that row

Here's my current code; I tried `iloc`, `melt`, `stack/unstack`, `mask`, `np.where`, `np.select` and other things but can't get the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

N = 6 # the width of our column-slices of interest

# Sample dataframe
dat = pd.compat.StringIO("""
text,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6\n
'foo',9,3,4,2,1,,      21,22,23,24,25,26\n
'bar',2,3,4,6,5,,      31,32,33,34,35,36\n
'baz',7,3,4,1,,,       11,12,13,14,15,16\n
'qux',2,6,3,4,7,,      41,42,43,44,45,46\n
'gar',3,1,4,7,,,       51,52,53,54,55,56\n
'wal',3,,,,,,          11,12,13,14,15,16\n
'fre',2,3,4,6,5,,      61,62,63,64,65,66\n
'plu',2,3,4,9,1,,      71,72,73,74,75,76\n
'xyz',2,3,4,9,6,1,     81,82,83,84,85,86\n
'thu',1,3,6,4,5,,      51,52,53,54,55,56""".replace(' ',''))

df = pd.read_csv(dat, header=[0])

v = 1 # For example; Actually we want to sweep v from 1:9 ...

# On each row, find the index 'i' of column 'm<i>' which equals v; or NaN if v doesn't occur

df.iloc[:, 1:N+1] == v

(df.iloc[:, 1:N+1] == 1).astype(np.int64)
#    m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6
# 0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 3   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 4   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 5   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 6   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 7   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 8   0   0   0   0   0   1
# 9   1   0   0   0   0   0

# np.where() seems useful...
_ = np.where((df.iloc[:, 1:N+1] == 1).astype(np.int64))
# (array([0, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9]), array([4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 0]))

# But you can't directly use df.iloc[ np.where((df.iloc[:, 1:N+1] == 1).astype(np.int64)) ]
# Feels like you want something like df.iloc[ *... ] where we can pass in our intermediate result as separate vectors of row- and col-indices

# can't unpack the np.where output into separate row- and col- indices vectors
irow,icol = *np.where((df.iloc[:, 1:N+1] == 1).astype(np.int64))
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here

# ...so unpack manually...
irow = _[0]
icol = _[1]
# ... but now can't manage to slice the `x<i>` with those...
df.iloc[irow, 7:13] [:, icol.tolist()] 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

# Want to get numpy-type indexing, rather than pandas iloc[]
# This also doesn't work:
df.iloc[:, 7:13] [list(zip(*_))]

# Want to slice into the x<i> which are located in df.iloc[:, N+1:2*N+1]

# Or any alternative faster numpy/pandas implementation...
```

Comment: I think the question is clear, but let me know if you want me to post the expected result Series...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability, and to avoid *float* notation in *df*, I first used
the following instruction to change *NaN* values to 0 and change their type to *int*:

```
df.fillna(0, downcast='infer', inplace=True)
```

## SOLUTION 1

And now get down to the main task, for *v == 1*. Start with:

```
x1 = np.argwhere(df.iloc[:, 1:N+1].values == v)
```

The result is:

```
[[0 4]
 [2 3]
 [4 1]
 [7 4]
 [8 5]
 [9 0]]
```

They are indices of elements *== v* in the subset of *df*.

Then, to "shift" to indices of the **target** elements, in the **whole** *df*,
we have to add **7** (actually, *N+1*) to each column index:

```
x2 = x1 + [0, N+1]
```

The result is:

```
[[ 0 11]
 [ 2 10]
 [ 4  8]
 [ 7 11]
 [ 8 12]
 [ 9  7]]
```

And to get the result (for *v == 1*), execute:

```
df.values[tuple(x2.T)]
```

The result is:

```
array([25, 14, 52, 75, 86, 51], dtype=object)
```

Alternative: If you want the above result in a **single** instruction, run:

```
df.values[tuple((np.argwhere(df.iloc[:, 1:N+1].values == v) + [0, N+1]).T)]
```

The procedure described above gives result for *v == 1*.
It is up to you how to assemble results of each pass (for *v = 1..9*) into the
final result. You didn't decribe this detail in your question (or I failed
to see and understand it).

One of possible solutions is:

```
pd.DataFrame([ df.values[tuple((np.argwhere(df.iloc[:, 1:N+1].values
    == v) + [0, N+1]).T)].tolist() for v in range(1,10) ],
    index=range(1,10)).fillna('-')
```

giving the following result:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  25  14  52  75  86  51   -   -   -   -
2  24  31  41  61  71  81   -   -   -   -
3  22  32  12  43  51  11  62  72  82  52
4  23  33  13  44  53  63  73  83  54   -
5  35  65  55   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
6  34  42  64  85  53   -   -   -   -   -
7  11  45  54   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
8   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
9  21  74  84   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

Index values are taken from the current value of *v*.
It is up to you whether you are happy about default
**column** names (consecutive numbers from 0).

Additional remark: Remove apostrophes surrounding values in the first
column (e.g. change *'foo'* to just *foo*).
Otherwise these apostrophes are part of the column content, and I suppose
you don't want it.
Note that e.g. in the first row of your source column names are **without**
apostrophes and *read_csv* is clever enough to recognize them as *string*
values.

## EDIT - SOLUTION 2

Another, maybe simpler solution:

As we operate on the underlying *NumPy* table, instead of *.values*
in a number of points, start with:

```
tbl = df.values
```

Then, for a single *v* value, instead of *`argwhere`* use *`nonzero`*:

```
tbl[:, N+1:][np.nonzero(tbl[:, 1:N+1] == v)]
```

Details:

- `tbl[:, 1:N+1]` - the slice for *m...* columns.
- `np.nonzero(tbl[:, 1:N+1] == v)` - a **tuple** of lists - indices of
  the "wanted" elements, grouped by axis, so it can be **directly**
  used in indexation.
- `tbl[:, N+1:]` - the slice for *`x<i>`* columns.

An important difference between *`nonzero`* and *`argwhere`* is that
*`nonzero`* returns a **tuple** so adding of a "shift" value to the
column number is more difficult, so I decided to take a different
slice (for *`x<i>`* columns) instead.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is absolutely superb numpy wizardry! (In general it is best not to modify df in-place, but replacing nan with zero is harmless and reversible if later need to.) The `tuple((...).T)` step was non-obvious, I'm thinking of putting this all in a function `match_coords()`, also the offset `[0,N+1]` which can be abstracted by just saying "lookup the `d<i>` array", because in reality I have several other similar value-arrays `t<i>, c<i>` I also want to lookup. Yes, I will manually sweep `v` from 1:9, don't worry about that part.

Comment: ...Yes, I will manually sweep `v` from 1:9 at top-level of my analysis, don't worry about that part (unless you know how to simultaneously compute the result for all v = 1..9, but that might get messy. It's not essential).

Comment: Solution 2 using `nonzero` to return indices is even better! and avoids the `fillna`-inplace hack, since `==` always returns False for np.NaN (maximum pessimism). I wonder only about the memory-efficiency of the chained indexing on `tbl[:, N+1:2*N+1] [np.nonzero(...)]`, since that temporary slice `tbl[:, N+1:2*N+1]` has 500K rows, but I'll test that later